# Is it still an unline tag or does it mean something else?

Tags: html, css

I was looking to use the [Jssor Slider](http://www.jssor.com/) and in looking through the code I found a `<span u="arrowleft"...>` tag (which can be seen in this other question: [How to move a span to a different position in a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356353/how-to-move-a-span-to-a-different-position-in-a-div))

The `<u>` tag used to indicate underline, but I've never seen a `u=` tag. Whenever I try to google for it all that comes up is underline tag results. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it specifies the usage of ui element. jssor slider recognizes the
>   usage of every element in the slider.

[For more info.](https://github.com/jssor/slider/issues/4)

If you pass HTML validation, [here.](http://www.jssor.com/development/pass-html-validation.html)

Comment: Thank you: the HTML validation link is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see it is just a custom attribute they decided to use. Nothing to do with underline. It is invalid HTML5 though. It would be better to use `data-u` in stead. And it should work fine that way if I may believe the issue tracker:

https://github.com/jssor/slider/issues/4

And for future googling attempts, in `<u>` the 'u' is a tag, in `<span u='something'>` the 'u' is called an attribute.